# How to stop Razer Synapse driver popup from appearing?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, drivers

I use a Razer Deathadder mouse on Windows 8.1 (soon 10) and I still use the legacy driver, as I don't need or want Synapse. However, regularly I get an annoying near-full-screen pop-up of Synapse which I decline by choosing the "never remind me again"-option which apparently is ignored. How can I prevent this from happening again?

P.S.: Can I still use the legacy driver in Windows 10?

Comment: You can try to use it, but  it currently isn't supported by Razer, which is likely the reason it ignores your settings.

Comment: But it specifically *asks* me, wheter it should remind me and gives me the *never* option.

Comment: have you reported the bug to Razer?  Razer isn't known for high quality software.  You can try manually modifying what likely is a registry setting though.